# Integrate custom template in OS-Commerce

Tags: oscommerce, sts-simple-templatesystem

Is there any help site for OS-Commerce for beginners that includes how to integrate custom templates in an os-commerce cart..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of oscommerce are you after.

OSC3 is totally template based so basically you could create your own template and hack the OSC3 default template into it [found in the template folder/default] where as for OSC2 you can make use of the Simple template System linked here http://addons.oscommerce.com/info/1524

I would not really recommend using a template system with OSC2 as by itself its already slow let alone having a template system interpolating the code... Hence you will never get anywhere as to page download speed ranking.